# Dynamic Downloading Data and set to DevExtreme TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, devexpress

**Description of the situation:**

I have selectbox, I choose a person there (there, I download the entire list of employees from the database). I have two more fields (I would like to enter values ​​from other columns (same row) (data of this employee))

**Controller**

```
using AppEcp.Models;
using DevExtreme.AspNet.Data;
using DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;

namespace AppEcp.Controllers
{
    public class UzytkownicyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UzytkownicyDbContext _uzytkownicyContext;

        public UzytkownicyController(UzytkownicyDbContext uzytkownicyContext)
        {
            _uzytkownicyContext = uzytkownicyContext;
        }

          public IActionResult GetItems(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
        {
            var GetMethod = _uzytkownicyContext.Uzytkownicy.Where(i => i.Firma == "Pekao Leasing").Select(i => new
            {
                i.Id,
                i.Nazwa,
                i.Departament,
                i.Login
            });

            return Json(DataSourceLoader.Load(GetMethod, loadOptions));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetDepartmentAndManager(string nazwaValue)
        {
            var danePracownika = _uzytkownicyContext.Uzytkownicy.Where(x => x.Nazwa == nazwaValue).Select(s => new 
            {
                UserDepartament = s.Departament,
                UserManager = s.Manager
            });

            return Json(danePracownika);
        }
    }
}
```

**I tried:**

**cshtml page**

````
                          @(Html
                           .DevExtreme()
                           .SelectBox()
                           .ID("Id_name")
                           .DataSource(d => d
                               .Mvc()
                               .Controller("Uzytkownicy")
                               .Key("Id")
                               .LoadAction("GetItems")
                           )
                           .DisplayExpr("Nazwa")
                           .ValueExpr("Id")
                           .SearchEnabled(true)
                           .OnValueChanged("getDepAndMan")
                        )
                        @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
                       .ID("Id_department"))

                        @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
                           .ID("Id_manager"))


<script type="text/javascript">

    function getDepAndMan() {

        var nazwaValue = document.getElementById("Id_name").value;

        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: '@Url.Action("GetDepartmentAndManager", "Uzytkownicy")',
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             data: { nazwaValue : nazwaValue},
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("Id_department").value = (data.UserDepartament);
                document.getElementById("Id_manager").value = (data.UserManager);
             },
             error: function () {
                alert("bad code noob");
             }
         });
    }
</script>```
````

**Do not work:**
The code does not throw an error, but does not enter the downloaded data into text boxes

Answer (score 0):

Access the required widget using its "options" api (refer to [this](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPNetCore/Demo/TextBox/Overview/) demo), for example:

```
success: function (data) {
    alert(data.UserDepartament + " " + data.UserManager);

    //document.getElementById("Id_department").value = (data.UserDepartament);
    //document.getElementById("Id_manager").value = (data.UserManager);

    $("#Id_department").dxTextBox("instance").option("value", data.UserDepartament);
    $("#Id_manager").dxTextBox("instance").option("value", data.UserManager);
}
```